# Get list of eye colors via wikidata API

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

For example, I need to get list of eye colors with wikidata API:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1340

Is it possible to receive names of the colors without SPARQL queries?

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=P1340&languages=en

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find it easier via [SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcolor%20%3FcolorLabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%3Fs%20wdt%3AP1340%20%3Fcolor.%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0A). Then you can, eventually, use the item ids (e.g. Q17122705) to query for the label like [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=wbgetentities&ids=Q17122705&languages=en&props=labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need SPARQL at least to get the colors ids ([query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcolor%20%3FcolorLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fwhoever%20wdt%3AP1340%20%3Fcolor%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%20100%0A) / [json](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcolor%20%3FcolorLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fwhoever%20wdt%3AP1340%20%3Fcolor%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%20100%0A%0A))

Then from the gathered ids you can build the general API query:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&languages=en&format=json&ids=Q270024|Q2367101|Q17122705|Q16939403|Q1088|Q3133|Q47071|Q23444|Q17122740|Q17122834|Q17244465|Q17244894|Q17122854|Q17126729|Q17291407|Q17245659

or request only the labels:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&languages=en&format=json&ids=Q270024|Q2367101|Q17122705|Q16939403|Q1088|Q3133|Q47071|Q23444|Q17122740|Q17122834|Q17244465|Q17244894|Q17122854|Q17126729|Q17291407|Q17245659&props=labels